# 2 Dimensional Pie Chart

Tags: r, visualization, pie-chart

I need to create a plot in R based on a dataset of information. I would like to produce 5 pie charts that shows the percentage of each type of crime that occurs and in what region it is most frequent for that year. I've already gotten one pie chart to appear showing the frequency of the regions but i am having trouble with the crime type.

I am only focused on the female responses 
I would be comparing rows "newoff" and "region"
Essentially i am trying to create 5 pie charts from my locations table

Here is a link to download the [Data](http://www.bjs.gov/developer/ncvs/data/csv/NCVS_PERSONAL_2010-2014.zip)

```
crime <- read.csv("PERSONAL_VICTIMIZATION_2010-2014.csv", sep=",")
female_crime <- subset(crime, gender!="1")
locations <- table(female_crime$region, female_crime$newoff,female_crime$year)
locations
```

Comment: Are you really committed to using pie charts? To quote from Edward Tufte "the only thing worse than one pie chart is lots of them". Human perception is much better at distinguishing lengths than angles. For critiques of why bar charts are typically better, see e.g. http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart#Use.2C_effectiveness_and_visual_perception

Comment: ha! no i am not committed to the pie charts , which ever way you feel works best for displaying this information,open to advice

Comment: Have a look at the lattice package.  Maybe try something like barchart(frequency.of.crime.type ~ region | year)

Comment: i really am sort of new to R, and i am not sure how to use this package, i just tried and am not getting any success just a bunch of error messages.

Comment: something like `barplot(with(mtcars, table(gear, cyl)), beside = TRUE)` ?